# Splitting and Replacing - and — in a string

Tags: python, split, long-integer, short

### Problem Description:

I just discover that there is at least 2 types of dash actually 3 anyway. I get a list of files:
result = list(desktop.glob("*.pdf"))
Each line of result is a string with - and — in it (it might not be obvious here but the 2 - are different: here is the ascii code for each one: alt+045, alt+0151.

My intial goal was to split on -(alt+045) in order to do my stuff on the string. But I always add —(alt0151) in my string :-( Because the story about the two dash...

So I tried to replace all the —(alt+0151) by -(alt+045) but I was unable because the replace function doesnt seem to accept ascii code, or (it is possible) I didn't do it as it is expected.

### Question:

1 / Is there a way to split on -(alt+045) and —(alt+0151)?
2 / If 1 is not possible is there a way to replace —(alt+0151) by -(alt+045)
3 / I quickly looked on internet and found nothing about Python dealing with this issue but once again I might not have looking for properly...

I tried to use split() and replace() with ascii code without success.
I looking for a way to use split() on -(alt+045) AND on —(alt+0151).

Comment: *str.replace()* takes *str* type as its first two arguments and thus any character in the ASCII character set (plus a lot more besides) can be handled. You should probably show the code you're struggling with

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Everyone, First of all sorry for not having providing enough info this is the first time I am using Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi Everyone, First sorry for not having providing enough info this is the first time I am using Stack Overflow.
So I am listing a directory in which I have files with name like this:
xx-name1—dirtyname.pdf (xx is an integer and I don't want to keep it, dirtyname a string that i don't want to keep)
So I wanted to write a simple program to split on - and — in order to keep only name1, so ideally I was expected to get a list of files renamed: name1.pdf, name2.pdf etc...
So I tried str.split("-").split("—") so it splits on the - but not on —

Comment: Just to clarify the replace I tried later was just in order to attempt to fix the problem I had with split() so as a workaround I tried to replace —(alt+0151) by standard -(alt+045) in all my files name.

Comment: I am listing a directory content: # Create a Path object desktop = pathlib.Path(r"W:\Perso\blabla") result = list(desktop.glob("*.pdf")) # I want to get all my pdf # From here my goal is to rename my pdf files. # initial format: xx(integer)-string—rubishString.pdf The first dash is alt+045 the second one is alt+0151. I am looking for to split on - in order to rename my files in keeping only the string and get rid off XX and rubishString. The problem I got is that python can split on -(alt+045) but not on — (alt+0151) when I am looking for splitting on both.enter code here.

Comment: Ok I found the solution to my problem !!!
    desktop = pathlib.Path(r"W:\path_where_my_pdf_are_stored")
    result = list(desktop.glob("*.pdf"))
    for line in result:
        str_encoded = str(line).encode('utf8', 'strict')
        print(str_encoded.decode("utf8").replace(u"–", "-").split("-")[1])

This solved my problem and I can now split on both -(alt+045) and —(alt+0151)

Comment: Ok I found the solution to my problem !!!

        str_encoded = str(line).encode('utf8', 'strict')
        print(str_encoded.decode("utf8").replace(u"–", "-").split("-")[1])

This is solving my problem and I can now split on both -(alt+045) and —(alt+0151)